# How to get an object reference for the non static field

Tags: c#

i have an observable collection that i need to use in static method. How do i make an object reference?

```
public  ObservableCollection<ArticleDetailData> LastThreeArticles { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ArticleDetailData>();
```

I have tried

```
_lastThreeAricles = new ObservableCollection<ArticleDetailData>LastThreeArticles;
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you would be using this static variable? also - do you know about the singleton design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to assume your collection exists in this class:

```
public class MyArticlesBrowserViewModel {
  public ObservableCollection<ArticleDetailData> LastThreeArticles { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ArticleDetailData>();
}
```

Then create a new `instance` of this class which contains the reference to the collection:

```
public static void MyStaticMethod() {
  var myArticlesBrowserViewModel = new MyArticlesBrowserViewModel();
  // This is your instance
  var myCollection = myArticlesBrowserViewModel.LastThreeArticles;
}

public static void Clean()
{
  var myArticlesBrowserViewModel= new MyArticlesBrowserViewModel(); 
  myArticlesBrowserViewModel.LastThreeArticles.Clear();
}
```

Comment: hi,  public static void Clean()
        {
          var myArticlesBrowserViewModel= new MyArticlesBrowserViewModel();
            var myCollection = myArticlesBrowserViewModel.LastThreeArticles.Clear;


        }

Comment: Now i get error that i cannot asign method group to implicitly typed variable

Comment: OK so it looks like you want to clear the collection in this static method? Have updated answer to reflect this. Keep in mind, if you're clearing the collection, your reference to it will probably exist somewhere else rather than in the static method (which we're currently creating).